# Acer V5-552G On Ubuntu 15.04 64bit

Tags: acer

I have Acer V5-552G 
with AMD Quad Core 10-5757M Processor 
AMD Radeon HD 8750M Graphics.

What essentials software I need to install specific for this hardware?
Thanks!

Edit: I'm missing the great audio I have when I'm still on Windows 8.1 with Dolby.
Something similar for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If everything works, then you do not need to install any drivers.
The only driver to consider is a video one. You can go to

System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers and install a proprietary driver.

Comment: Edit: I'm missing the great audio I have when I'm still on Windows 8.1 with Dolby.
Something similar for Ubuntu?

Comment: Then ask a specific question regarding this audio. Specify what is audio chip, and what do you miss.

Answer (score 0):

Only drivers that you would ever need are graphics Drivers. However the FGLRX Drivers are a bit tricky. Considering that this laptop has an Integrated Graphics Card and a Dedicated Graphics Card as well. Both are AMD Make, Which makes it rather interesting. It uses something called Hybrid X-Fire.

This is supposed to automatically swtich the GPU from Integrated to Dedicated GPU as required, Much like Nvidia Optimus. However most of the people using this have not had much luck even on Windows.

So just a word of caution, You should be good with the latest proprietary FGLRX Drivers from Ubuntu Repos. If not you have an option to use the Installer from the AMD Website as well.

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64

Get it from there

Comment: I would NOT recommend to use installer from AMD site.

Comment: Doe the installer on AMD site tested and surely will work fine?

Comment: Yes I have used it many times. You need to build the debs for Ubuntu and then use dkpg command line to install the debs. I mean when you download the driver from AMD Site you get a run file. If you use this switch --buildpkg ubuntu/Vivid with the run file you can generate the Deb Files for Ubuntu. You then just need to install the resulting deb files using dpkg.

Comment: Can you point the exact link?

Comment: I already tried it before on Mint but got an error during installation.

Comment: Were you able to generate the required Deb Files? Or the error happened during building of the debs? If it happened during installation, please post the error details so I can help!